# embedding of finite groups into product

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Our situation is following. Assume that we have free product $\star_{i<n} G_i$ each $G_i$ finite group and assume that we have normal subgroup $K$ such that composition of canonical embedding and the quotinet mapping $G_i\to \star_{i<n}G_i\to \star_{i<n}G_i/K$ is still embedding. Is there bigger normal subgroup $L>K$ such that $G_i\to \star_{i<n}G_i\to \star_{i<n}G_i/L$ is still embedding and $\star_{i<n}G_i/L$ is finite?

Comment: Question is answered below and in the discussion there is additional question so I state it here as well. What if K is given by finitely many relations?

Comment: The answer is surely still 'no'. You are asking if there is an infinite, finitely presented, simple group generated by torsion. Infinite finitely presented simple groups are not so easy to construct, but there is no reason why such a group should not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, unless you restrict somehow the prime divisors of $|G_i|$. Take $G_i = \mathbb{Z}/p_i$ where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number. Take $K$ to be the trivial subgroup. Now, if you have such a subgroup $L$ then on the one hand $*_i G_i/L$ is finite, and on the other hand, it contains an element of order $p_i$ for every $i$, which is impossible.

Comment: I am sorry I have already corrected that the product is finite I mean made of finitely many finite groups but thank you for quick answer.

Comment: The answer is still no. Consider Corollary A in the following http://www.math.tamu.edu/~sunik/schupp.pdf . It says that there exists an infinite simple group $S$ generated by a pair of elements of finite order. In other words, there exists a quotient $\mathbb{Z}_p*\mathbb{Z}_q\rightarrow S$. Denote the kernel by $K$. Then $K$ is maximal with the property you wrote since $S$ is simple. But the quotient by $K$ is infinite.

Comment: ok thank you that solves the problem

Comment: One additional question is the answer still the same if we assume that the K in my question is finitely generated?

Comment: Do you mean finitely generated group, or finitely generated as a normal subgroup?

Comment: as a normal subgroup, add just finitely many relations